# JSONP function with integral callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp

I am trying to create a JSONP function that returns the data using a callback from the function that was called, rather than using a seperate callback function.

```
// JOSONP request.
function jsonp(url,cb){
  _jsoncb = function(data) {cb(data)}    
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    async: false,
    jsonpCallback: '_jsoncb',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp'
  });
}
```

This works in Firefox, but not in Chrome ?

The error is: "TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'res.match(/jQuery.*((.*));/)')"

Comment: any console errors perhaps?

Comment: `fully self contained` - no it isn't. `_jsoncb` is a global

Comment: Yes, Uncaught TypeError: res.match is not a function

Comment: is that error in your code or in jqueery library?

Comment: If you declare the cb function within th scope of main function it is not found, so it has to be global, unless there's another way of doing this ?

Comment: I'm just saying, your assertion that this is in any way `fully self contained` is wrong, and this code will have issues as soon as you try and use it while another request is "in flight" - doesn't jqueery already handle jsonp for you?

Comment: No. With JSON-P, the callback can't be completely localized to the scope within `jsonp()`. [JSON-P](http://json-p.org/) works by loading the response as a `<script>`, expecting it to invoke the globally-accessible callback. Same as in other scripts you may be using, it's unable to reach functions contained entirely within other scopes. (Since you're using jQuery, if you let it define the callback, it will expose the callback [as a method of the global, `window` object](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2.1.4/src/ajax/jsonp.js#L56-L60).)